# Sed: Search and replace on a 4GB one-line file

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed

OS: 14.04
sed: 4.2.4

I have multiple large files (2-4gb) that I want to perform some simple manipulations on. The entire file is in one line, which makes me wonder how to perform sed operations on it.

There are three things I want to do with each file:

1) Remove all `[` characters

2) Remove all `]` characters

3) Replace all occurrences of `},{` with `}{`.

So far I have tried `sed -e 's/},{/}{/g' file.json > file_new.json` with and without the `g` option, without any luck. I have also tried `sed -e 's/\[//g' file.json > file_new.json` without any luck. I only get a duplicate file.

Any ideas?

Comment: awk or perl are more appropriate for this task since sed works by line. Is it a good idea to put a json extension to the new file?

Comment: Is this a problem that only occurs on 2G+ files?  Can you extract a small portion of the file that still exhibits the problem - e.g., `head -c 80`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With gnu awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="},{";OFS="}{";RS="[][]";ORS=""}$1=$1' file
```

Perhaps faster with perl *(must be tested)*:

```
perl -0135 -pe 's/},{/}{/g;y/][//d' file
```

Where 135 stands for the character `]` in octal. The -0 option defines the record separator (instead of to be read line by line, the file is read by parts from and until each `]`)

The goal of these two scripts is to avoid to load the whole file in memory.

---

To store the result in a file:

You can redirect the output.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="},{";OFS="}{";RS="[][]";ORS=""}$1=$1' file > result
```

or

```
perl -0135 -pe 's/},{/}{/g;y/][//d' file > result
```

You can use command line options:

```
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak 'BEGIN{FS="},{";OFS="}{";RS="[][]";ORS=""}$1=$1' file
```

or

```
perl -0135 -pi'*.bak' -e 's/},{/}{/g;y/][//d' file
```

*(these two commands create a backup of the original file adding the extension .bak, if you want to change the source file in place, remove `-v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak` for gawk, and `'*.bak'` for perl.)*

Comment: Yeah, that will perform perfectly. We did some analysis in a related post a time ago (ask Ed :) ) and compared that to perl, sed, ... Nothing than a specialized and well written C program can beat the above `awk` code! (Not even remotely)

Comment: @hek2mgl: thanks, I added a perl version that may be faster.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte perl is usually slower since it's PCRE regexp engine is very slow due to the possible complexity of regexps it has to support and unfortunately it is invoked and chugs slowly along even when the regexp it's operating on is a BRE or ERE. See https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html and google others. wrt the awk script - I always worry when I see `$1=$1` as the condition instead of an action `{$1=$1}1` - are you using that deliberately to, say, delete blank lines?

Comment: @EdMorton: There's only one line. I know the complexity difference between a backtracking engine and BRE/ERE, but note that here there are no quantifiers, and I must say that I have several times noticed unexpected good performances for a perl script that does the same thing than an awk script.

Comment: Thanks, just left the office. Will test it tomorrow!

Comment: @kongshem: go back to the office immediately!

Comment: Lets all delete all our answers and comments - that'll teach him to leave the office without permission! (I am joking of course!).

Comment: haha @CasimiretHippolyte. Is there a good page for the perl -options? Running `perl -0135 -pe 's/},{/}{/g;y/][//d' file` prints to console which makes the operation take forever. It seems however that the command works! :)

Comment: @kongshem: if you want to redirect the output to a file, you can use `whateverthecommand > newfile` or with the perl or awk command you can use the option `-i` (like in sed): for example `-i'*.bak'` will rename the source file adding the extension `.bak` and save the result with the source filename. Be careful if you use `-i` alone, you will loose the original file (i stands for "in place").

Comment: Thanks. After testing both Perl and Tr, the run time is approximately the same (5-10) seconds depending on the file size. I prefer to use `perl` over `tr` just because of the one-line command and not having to run two separate commands. I will accept your answer, but for other readers, `tr` works as well.

Comment: @kongshem: I added a description of how you can store the result in a file.

Answer (score 1):

When I've got huge single-line files like that, for which the usual line-based tools won't work, I usually turn to: `tr`!

> 1) Remove all [ characters
> 2) Remove all ] characters

That's easy:

```
tr -d '[]' < file > strippedfile
```

(This might not work with a really, really old SysV version of tr, but it should be fine with any modern version.)

> 3) Replace all occurrences of },{ with }{.

That's trickier, because you care about context, so it's really a job for `sed`.  One kludge I've used is to use `tr` to temporarily change some other character to a newline -- that is, to temporarily change the huge single-line file into a multi-line file -- then run `sed`, and finally change it back to a single-line file.  Something like

```
tr '{' '\n' < file | sed 's/},$/}/' | tr '\n' '{' > newfile
```

This last works *only* if the original file contains *no* newlines.  You could run through `tr -d '\n'` first to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, just left the office. Will test it tomorrow!

Comment: @kongshem: You're welcome, glad you're making progress.  I wanted to add that while any of these techniques are fine for a one-off conversion, if you're going to be doing this on a long-term basis it would really be worth investing in a proper json parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to place a newline at the end of the file:

```
echo "" >> file
sed 'whatever' file
```

Many UNIX tools will simply not recognize a file with no ending newlines as a text file and so will not operate on them so that MAY be your problem. If that doesn't work then edit your question to include a concise, testable example of your file.

Comment: Thanks, just left the office. Will test it tomorrow!

Comment: He's got 2+ Gb with no newlines.  That's too long a line for most line-based tools to deal with no matter what.

Comment: The OP isn't using "most line-based tools", though, he's using GNU sed on ubuntu and AFAIK that sed should be fine with that line, see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html.

Comment: Huh!  Not something I would ever depend on, but good to know.  Thanks.